# Texture Painting: Paint appears elsewhere

Tags: sculpting, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint a sculpt. I believe the UV Unwrap worked properly as seen in the image. Though when I want to paint on the lips, it appears else where on the head, as seen in the image.

What am I missing?

All responses appreciated! Thank You[image]

Comment: it may be because you have overlapping UVs (in that case the unwrap is not correct and you should redo it) or inverted normals?